# Can't log in - Laravel 5.3 - Cloudways Application

Tags: php, mysql, git, laravel-5.3, cloudways

I can't log in and I don't understand why. I tried a lot of thing since 4 days. I use git. The problem exist only onto the web server. Onto my test environment, every thing just work fine. When I try to log in onto the server, I am getting no error into the log.

Test :
Windows 10, with Vagrant, Homestead, Laravel 5.3, php 7.0

Server : 
Cloudways, Laravel 5.3, php 5.6

I am using the Auth system from laravel and I can log in for few seconds when I use the remember me checkbox. After the delay, it kick me out. I don't understand what happen, because the only difference between the 2 server is the .env file. I just did a backup to the creating date of the server, redeploy the with git and I also did a MySql dump to have everything as it's on the Test one.

For sure, I did all these command line :

`php artisan clear-compile
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload
php artisan session:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear`

Please help me.

**EDIT**
I just made some change into the code. But first, I need to explain a little more the problem. I realised that I can login if I use "remember me" checkbox. The things is I was not kicked out. I got token mismatch error line 67 on every post. The issue was, instead of adding a csrf field into every different forms, I added a meta field with the token in the layout. Now, my post work fine.

I'm still not able to login if I don't use the checkbox remember me... (Just put it checked by default...) Still looking for the issue.

Comment: Make sure you have given the permission to the folder storage/logs on the server

Comment: Is your local version in development and your remote in production? Put your local into production- run your commands above and report the outcome back here if this is the case.

Comment: @Vikash I always forgot about this one... But I don't understand why it worked for 2 weeks then it stop... Now it's good.

Jonathan Both are in production. Now everything work fine... But I don't really understand why.

Comment: Its better you write a bash command for this, I mean when you pull your code on server then all these cache clear things with all required permission   by running a singe command.

Comment: @Vikash You're right, I'm gonna save a lot of time! Thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it can be related to the PHP version on cloudways. Laravel 5.3 requires PHP 5.6.4 or higher (according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade)  but I think the PHP version on cloudways is 5.6.2